# Solspace Freeform Error with repeated domain in Action URL

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

Solspace Freeform is generating a form tag with the domain repeated multiple times and is causing an error:

```
<form action="DOMAIN.com/DOMAIN.com/DOMAIN.com/?ACT=28" accept-charset="utf-8" method="post">
```

The following errors were encountered:
Missing required valid POST variable - params_id

Any ideas on the cause?

```
{exp:freeform:form
   form_name="web-inquiry"
   required="first_name|last_name|email|issue"
   form:class="form-stacked"
   }
<fieldset>
    <legend>Contact Us</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
        <div class="controls">
                <input class="form-control required" id="first_name" name="first_name" size="30" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
        <div class="controls">
                <input class="form-control required" id="last_name" name="last_name" size="30" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <div class="controls">
                <input class="form-control required email" id="email" name="email" size="30" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="issue">Issue:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control required" id="issue" name="issue" rows="5"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions pad-bottom-30">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>&nbsp;<button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</fieldset>
{/exp:freeform:form}
```

Comment: Freeform and EE versions, please. Also, please provide your Freeform template code. Very likely it's one of the parameters, or an EE setting, that needs to be tweaked.

Comment: I'm using EE v2.9.2 and Freeform v4.2.0.

Comment: Also, please provide your Freeform template code. You should be able to edit your Opening Post (OP) and add the code.

Comment: Also, what are your EE settings for **Name of your site's index page** and **URL to the root directory of your site** (a.k.a. the "`site_url`")? (General Settings in the EE CP) If it's not the case now, try using an absolute URL for the site URL.

Comment: The Name of the index page is blank and the URL is http://DOMAIN.com.  Changing these settings does not fix the issue.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Anyone got this issue solved?